# Old styles information are present after getStylesheets().clear()

Tags: css, javafx-2

I want to provide styles changing for user in application. I have folder with styles, also I placed there default caspian.css. But when I switch style between some-custom-style.css (which changes background color of application) to default caspian.css - background color doesn't changes, it still same as in some-custom-style.css. My method for changing:

```
    private void changeStyleSheet(String stylePath){
        this.getScene().getStylesheets().clear();
        this.getScene().getStylesheets().add(stylePath);
    }
```

I thought that after this.getScene().getStylesheets().clear() all styles information will be deleted, but it steel present... So, how can I totally delete affects of css styles? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this information is useful - guys from "ODT Discussion Forum" helped me (https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10239015&#10239015), so it's a bug that will be fixed in version 2.1